# Nginx allow PHP file for some IP only

Tags: linux, nginx, configuration

I'm using the following instruction to block the execution of several file types

```
location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

How can I allow the execution of only one PHP script for some specific IP address?

I tried the following to allow the execution of one PHP script, but is not working..

```
location ~ ^adminer.php {                                        
    fastcgi_pass   php-fpm:9000;  
    fastcgi_index  adminer.php;              
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;          
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE        "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
    include  fastcgi_params;                       
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To block user based on ip use "allow - deny" instructions as described on [ngx_http_access_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html)
Then you could add a catch all rule, if you need it.

```
location ~* phpinfo.php {                                        
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;  
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;          
    include  fastcgi_params;                       
    allow your.exact.i.p/32;
    deny all;
}

location ~* \.(?:php|htaccess|git)$ {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: very nice answer !

Answer (score 1):

Use `location = /path/to/adminer.php` as your location block. The `=` match is highest priority in nginx, and other `location` blocks are not matched after that.

In your configuration, it is most likely the order of your `location` blocks and overlapping matches which prevent it from working.